Gnosis Safe App list integration in my website via iframe
I want to integrate this safe app list function https://app.safe.global/apps  in my wallet project website (say it's example.com ).
Wallet users will be able to use this app within context of my wallet project website  example.com, via embedded iframe of app.safe.global.
I know this is currently impossible to embed app.safe.global as iframe in my website example.com, because X-Frame-Options: sameorigin is specified for app.safe.global.
If I want to integrate this app list as a company, I need to talk to someone to modify X-Frame-Options: sameorigin, likely by paying extra money or making legal agreement. Where should I contact?
(By the way, I can also host this web app by myself: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-wallet-web . But then, each and every safe app must also add my domain  example.com to its whitelist, and I don't think that is smart.)
Related question: Why can't I load Safe App in an iframe?
(I originally posted this on Discord and was told to post here first: https://discord.com/channels/907968493134155807/915922168846618674/1318778886259085392 )

The answer on the question you cited is pretty complete already: Safe is doing this for security reasons, as allowing embedding an iframe in other domains would expose its users to clickjacking attacks.
Safe is determined to keep its users safe at all times and does not currently propose commercial agreements for whitelisting external domains for embedding iframes.
I hope I answered your question. If I did, could you kindly mark it as solved? If not, please let me know 
Thank you in advance.
Best, Louis

Thank you for the reply, it answered question. I marked it as resolved.
